# How to track which commits got transformed into which others with filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am running a `filter-branch` command to wrap the contents of my repo in a directory. This is using GitPython but it should be clear what is going on for anyone familiar with the command line

```
repo.git.filter_branch(f'--force', '--tree-filter', f"""
  mkdir {name} \
  && ls | grep -v {name} | xargs -I % mv % {name}
""", '@')
```

After this runs, I need to update the refs to point to their corresponding new commits. What I would like therefore is to build up a map so that I can see - given the old commit sha - what the new one is. [I know there are some variables and functions available](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_filters) in the filters themselves to help with this. But I'm not sure that helps - sure I can get the *old* commit, but the new commit sha isn't calculated until my filter has run.

Comment: The shell-script `git filter-branch` *command* does the ref name rewrites for you. Presumably GitPython should do the same. The way the script achieves this is to keep a mapping from old hash to new hash; unfortunately, the script *removes* this mapping when it exits (it should preserve it, or have an option to preserve it, as The BFG does).

Comment: @torek it does not. I've ran this in both GitPython and the command line, my old refs remain pointed to where they were and I have to go in and manually update them

Comment: That seems rather broken. Why not use GitPython's ability to run raw shell commands to run `git filter-branch` itself, then? (Or dig into the source and see where/how/why it is broken like this.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure when you do anything in `GitPython` from the `git` object it just shells out. But like I said, I've run this manually from the command line and gotten the same result. I would have thought it would update the refs too but it did not. Digging into git source...while that sounds like fun, I'm not much of a C guy and honestly not the best use of my time here.

Comment: I meant the GitPython source (not all of it uses shell directly, as I understand things anyway—I have glanced at the Python code but not really used it for anything) but if you convert this into a command-line `git filter-branch` question, rather than a GitPython question, we might get somewhere more productive, because the command line filter-branch *does* update (some) refs. (At this point, to convert, I'd just close/delete this original question and write a new one...)

Comment: right but what I'm saying @torek is this question isn't about GitPython at all, I can rewrite it if you want. Thats just the copy paste I had handy, but I've written this on the command line before as well and same thing